# Регулярное выражение: запретить ники вида vk1212212

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

При регистрации для поля Логин у меня стоит такая регулярка
 `/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]+$/u`

Как мне ее изменить, чтобы она исключала слово vk1212212 (может быть пробел между vk и цифрами, цифры любые) ?
Спасибо!

Comment: Странный вопрос. Скорее всего Вы пытаетесь таким неправильным путем какую-то другую проблему.

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы люди перестали регистрировать такие логины : vk21212323 и т.д .. Как можно решить этот вопрос ?

Comment: вообще `/^(?!vk\s*\d+)[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]+$/`, только не проще ли отдельную проверку на это сделать, не зачем странные исключения в маску ввода совать

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего сделать вторую проверку по этому выражению: /vk\s*\d+/ такой код будет лучше читаться

```
if (preg_match('/^vk\s*\d+$/', $login)) {
    exit("неверный логин");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$login = "vk1212212";
if(!preg_match('/^(?!vk\s*\d+)[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]+$/u', $login)) {
  exit("регистрация запрещена");
}
```